# How to attach a specific variable value from a loop iterating to a one dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

i am doing a bucle for to get the keys from local storage archives and i want to attach that keys to dynamically created elements the way that when i click over the new created element (who recives the name of the storage file) it will alert the content. This is what i have, the problem is in archivo[ keys[i] ].

```
function local(){
    archivo = {};
    keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    i = 0; var key;


    for (i = 0; key = keys[i] ; i++) {

    var compra_recuperada = document.createElement('ons-list-item');

    compra_recuperada.innerHTML = keys[i];                                            
    document.getElementById('compra').appendChild(compra_recuperada); 
    archivo[ keys[i] ] = localStorage.getItem( keys[i] ); 
compra_recuperada.addEventListener('click', function(){ alert(archivo[ keys[i] ])  
})}};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: I think that with my simplification i expressed something different, i edit and post my real problem now.

Comment: Not really, you're still trying to use a loop variable (`i`) inside a callback and need to use a closure to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the declaration of variable `i` outside of the loop and change `for (i = 0; key = keys[i] ; i++)` to `for (let i = 0; key = keys[i]; i++)` should work for your case.

In the previous version, each element shares the same variable `i`. By the time you see the alert, it is already changed to the last value. The second version will create a new variable for each loop iteration thanks to the ES6 `let` keyword.